# Table borders are not shown in Word Document

Tags: vba, vbscript, ms-office, ms-word

I have spend some time trying to find how to add a border in my table. Any kind of border (i guess i will adjust it as i want when i see it :)).

I have tried a lot of methods i found on web but nothing seem to work for my case. Here is my vbscript.

I run the script via a simple double click (Windows 7 x64)

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
Set objSection = objDoc.Sections(1)

Const NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 3
Const NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 4
Set objRange = objDoc.Range()
objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, NUMBER_OF_ROWS, NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS
Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)
objTable.Borders.Enable = True
'a way i found on web, does nothing
With objTable.Borders
        .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .InsideColor = wdColorAutomatic
        .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .OutsideColor = wdColorAutomatic

    End With

objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "ΠΕΡΙΓΡΑΦΗ"
'another way i tried my self, does nothing aswell
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Borders.InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Borders.InsideColor = wdColorAutomatic
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Borders.InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "ΗΜΕΡΟΜΗΝΙΑ"
objTable.Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "ΧΙΛΙΟΜΕΤΡΑ"
objTable.Cell(1, 4).Range.Text = "ΠΑΡΑΤΗΡΗΣΕΙΣ"


objTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "text text"
objTable.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = "17/3/2018"
objTable.Cell(2, 3).Range.Text = "10000"
objTable.Cell(2, 4).Range.Text = "text"

objTable.Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = "a text"
objTable.Cell(3, 2).Range.Text = "17/3/2018"
objTable.Cell(3, 3).Range.Text = "10000"
objTable.Cell(3, 4).Range.Text = "a text"


objDoc.SaveAs("C:\Users\George\Desktop\AAA - 4355.docx")
objWord.Quit
```

Comment: I've found it easier to precreate a custom table style, transfer the raw data to a standard blank table then apply the custom style.

Comment: If you mean filling the cells first and then write the line With objTable.Borders .... I have tried it already, same thing.

Comment: You could record a macro while making the changes and them check out the generated code to learn

Comment: @ashleedawg Well this is something i did not think. I created a table with macro, went to see its code and it had this line objTable.Style = "Table Grid"....It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the statement

```
objTable.Borders.Enable = True
```

and try this to apply bottom border on cell(1,1)

```
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Borders(wdBorderBottom).Color = wdColorAutomatic
```